# Display two count from a single in two different column from a single table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table where I record daily work of employees. I have a query where I display the current work for today for each employee and have another query where I display the total count of work for each employee.

I want to combine the 2 queries into a single one where I have a daily column and a cumulative column.

my query is below:

```
SELECT staff, 
       process_inprogress, 
       not_yet_completed 
FROM   (SELECT staff, 
               Count(number)    AS Process_InProgress, 
               Count(team_name) AS Not_Yet_Completed 
        FROM   dbo.empty_shell_workflow 
        WHERE  ( end_date IS NULL ) 
               AND ( process_name IS NOT NULL ) 
               AND ( billing_amount IS NULL ) 
               AND ( deletion IS NULL ) 
               AND ( team_name = 'Team Vishma' ) 
               AND ( CONVERT(DATE, start_date) = CONVERT(DATE, Getdate()) ) 
        GROUP  BY staff 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT staff, 
               Count(number)    AS Process_InProgress, 
               Count(team_name) AS Not_Yet_Completed 
        FROM   dbo.empty_shell_workflow AS Empty_Shell_Workflow_1 
        WHERE  ( team_name = 'Team Vishma' ) 
               AND ( billing_amount IS NULL ) 
               AND ( tag_number IS NULL ) 
               AND ( initiator IS NOT NULL ) 
               AND ( end_date IS NULL ) 
               AND ( deletion IS NULL ) 
               AND ( process_name IS NOT NULL ) 
        GROUP  BY staff) AS t
```

however it is being display only in a single column for both daily and cumulative

Below is how i want it to display

```
Staff          Process_Progress(Daily)       Not_YetCompleted(Cumulative)
A                  2                                5
B                  0                                1
C                  6                                8
```

however from the query above, the cumulative is being display in the daily column

Any idea, how can I modify the query?

Comment: add some dummy data

Comment: dbms name please

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin Sql Server 2012

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpandeBharti Bolah 2 2
Kavina Boolaky 1 1
Neha Rosunee 2 2
Nirvana Govinda 1 1
Urshila Tacouri 3 3
Ali Joomun 10 10
Arshad Kureemun 24 24
Bharti Bolah 24 24
Claudine Troubat 4 4
Hanslall Cheeneebash 7 7
Kavina Boolaky 11 11
Mayur Ramdhul 44 44
Minachee Appavoo 1 1
Neha Rosunee 22 22
Nirvana Govinda 7 7
Riti Bikoo 27 27
Sweta Gunnack 1 1
Urshila Tacouri 16 16
Varun Chakouree 3 3
Vishma Ranlaul 8 8

Comment: Hey, not as a comment. Edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try like below by using case when

```
with cte as
   (    SELECT staff,CONVERT(DATE, start_date)  as date_of_month
                   Count(number)    AS Process_InProgress                       
            FROM   dbo.empty_shell_workflow AS Empty_Shell_Workflow_1 
            WHERE  ( team_name = 'Team Vishma' ) 
                   AND ( billing_amount IS NULL ) 
                   AND ( tag_number IS NULL ) 
                   AND ( initiator IS NOT NULL ) 
                   AND ( end_date IS NULL ) 
                   AND ( deletion IS NULL ) 
                   AND ( process_name IS NOT NULL ) 
            GROUP  BY staff,CONVERT(DATE, start_date)
) select staff, sum(case when date_of_month = CONVERT(DATE, Getdate()) then
             Process_InProgress else 0 end) as Process_Progress_Daily,
         sum(case when date_of_month != CONVERT(DATE, Getdate()) then
             Process_InProgress else 0 end) as Not_YetCompleted
             from cte
             group by staff
```